# can i get two events triggered on clicking one button or hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, forms, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox, bootstrap-modal

can i get two events triggered on clicking one button or hyperlink simultaneously?

I have a link( to sign-in) in light-box(modal of bootstrap). 
What i want to do is on clicking the link i want to have two thing done:

1. first close the existing light-box(registration form).
2. second call the another light-box(sign-in form.)

   ```
   lblwc.Text = "Thank You for Registration," + " " + name.Text + " | <a onclick=\"document.getElementById('signin').click();\">login</a> ";
   ```

Here i am able to call the sign-in light-box.But the existing light-box(registration form) blocks the newly called light-box.So i need to close the registration light box on the same click event.

Comment: please show the markup and the javascript. Also dont just go on writing the post u must also format the code snippets too..!

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out the following implementation does the required job.

```
lblwc.Text = "Thank You for Registration," + " " + name.Text + " | <a onclick=\"document.getElementById('close').click();document.getElementById('signin').click();\">login</a> ";
```

Here the first id is the id of the close button which closes the existing light-box(registratin form).

Next, the second id is the id of the button that pops up the light-box of sign-in form.

PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score -2):

You can simply trigger another events. For example:

My ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="Button 1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" 
OnClick="Button2_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button 1 and 2" 
OnClick="Button3_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl_output" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

... and code behind page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button3.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
        Button3.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_output.Text += "Button 1 clicked<br>";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_output.Text += "Button 2 clicked<br>";
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_output.Text += "Button 3 clicked<br>";
    }
```

In this example, button3 triggers button1 and button2,
so clicking on button 3 refers to

- button1 click
- button2 click
- button3 click

You can check out this page  http://www.reitix.com/Makaleler/Asp.Net-Button-Click-Events-Trigger/ID=2485